# Displaying an image in Silverlight 3 Datagrid without XAML

Tags: silverlight-3.0

I would like display text and an image in a Silverlight 3 datagrid (i.e. First name, last name, picture).  There were many examples on the web utilizing DataTemplate and RowDetailsTemplate in XAML.  However, I need to do this all through C# code.  Any examples would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sam,

Steps I'd take:

1. On your datagrid, set AutoGenerateColumns = false;
2. Create the columns for text columns and add them to datagrid.Columns
3. Create a DataTemplateColumn
4. Assign the DataTemplateColumn .CellTemplate property to the results of a method that looks something like this:

   ```
   public DataTemplate Create()
   {
       return (DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(
           @"<DataTemplate
           xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007"">
           <Image Source=""{Binding <your field here>}""/>
         </DataTemplate>"
         );
   }
   ```

Bind your grid to your datasource.

That should do it.